# IDEA does not find classes when rebuilding the project which builds with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project multiple people work on. Some classes and a new dependency were added in the last iteration. In the new classes, my IDE is marking the new imports that belong to the new dependency with "Cannot resolve symbol ''".
The other people working on this exact same project don't have problems with the new dependencies at all. I'm not able to build it.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

I did a "mvn clean install" sometimes this solved the issue. But it didn't change anything.
I did a "Invalidate Caches/Restart" in my IDEA.
I removed the ".idea" folder and let IDEA recreate it.
I removed the "system" folder of IDEA in "C:\Users<my name>\AppData\Local\JetBrains<IDEA version>" and let IDEA recreate it.
I asked the other people working on this project and they also did not see any error.

I did a rebuild / tried running the application. The error was "java: package  does not exist"

Also in the Project Settings tab, the libraries of Maven are not visible.

Are there any other suggestions, what I could do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: what kind of classes? generated sources? imported sources?

Comment: Modular java (with module-info.java) can also have effects (unlikely), The JDK/JRE version; maven should set source and target versions. Settings.xml from maven is often user specific.

Comment: Are there any errors in the idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) file? Have you tried the **Reload** action in Maven tool window? Show also the screenshot of the Maven tool window.

Comment: Check the **Dependencies** tab of the module - do you see the library jar for this dependency which provides these classes?

Comment: @Andrey In the logs, I'm able to see the following error:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for <artifact>

Comment: If project can be built from command line with Maven but fails from IDE, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach idea.log file after **Reload*8 action in Maven tool window and reproducing the issue.